# UITextView.attributedText, How to set numberOflines and lineBreakMode?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In some condition I have to use UITextView instead of UILabel(To make link attributes clickable).
Here is my code:

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest")
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
```

And here is my textView:

```
private lazy var titleTextView: UITextView = {
    let view = UITextView(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)
    view.isEditable = false
    view.textContainerInset = .zero
    view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    view.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2        // Set numberOflines here!
    view.textAlignment = .left
    view.isScrollEnabled = false
    view.delegate = self

    return view
}()
```

But maximumNumberOfLines property don't work, it display only 1 line and followed by "..."

[image]

Comment: Is it compulsory to you BKLinkTextView??

Comment: @Nirmalsinh Sorry, this has nothing to do with BKLinkTextView, so i replace it with UITextView, and the problem it's still exist.

Comment: Then try to use UILabel. It will more suitable and useful.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I can't ... I have NSAttributedStringKey.link and i want it to be clickable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `lineBreakMode` to a value that doesn't truncate.

Try

```
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Comment: Then the text won't followed by "...", and my requirement is to display multiple line, and text in last line followed by "...".

Answer (score 0):

When i set the linespacing property, the size computered by UITextView.sizeToFit() is not height enough to display more than 1 line.
But in UILabel, call sizeToFit will computer a appropriate height for you to display as more lines as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```swift
view.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2
view.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Answer (score 0):

removing `linebreakmode` of `paragraphStyle` used by attributed text works for me.